# How to increase the TTY fontsize?

Tags: command-line, fonts

I have a fedora machine, I am used to working on CLI since I had CRT monitor, after switching to TFT - the experience is not the same I had with CRT, the font is smaller now.

How to change it?

Comment: Do you mean the font size of a TTY, or of a terminal within X? If the latter, which terminal emulator?

Answer (score 6):

**updated answer**

Since you're using *Fedora*, the variable that you need to play with is `SYSFONT` in the file `/etc/sysconfig/i18n`. Play with the font-sizes ( 8, 12, 16, 32, etc ).

The avialable fonts are listed in `/lib/kbd/consolefonts/`.

You should be able to test the fonts by using `setfont` from your TTY:

```
$ setfont  /lib/kbd/consolefonts/iso07u-16.psfu.gz
```

**Note:** run `setfont` without any arguments to restore to default font, you might need to do this "blind" if one of the fonts messes up your display.

Refer to [Change console font in Fedora](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/09/30/change-console-font-in-fedora/).

---

**old answer**

Changing the fontsize of your CLI depends on a lot of things.

Firstly, as Michael mentioned in his comment, what CLI are we talking about? A CLI within [Xorg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) or a [TTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_%28Unix%29)?

*If this is a emulator within Xorg, you will need to specify wich emulator.* I will assume that you meant the TTY font size.

Before we started using [KMS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/KernelModeSetting) in our boot procedures, you could have changed the TTY font by adding `vga=blah` to grub's boot line and then playing arround with the values of `blah`. See this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=122936) on that.

If you are using **KMS**, things get more tricky. You will need to configure things withing your distro, and each distro has its own way of configuring things. Take a look at these two forum posts:

- [KMS & Manual tty modesetting](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=755281) - ArchLinux Forum
- [how do I change the console font?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=329369) - Ubuntu Forum

Comment: oh damm.. i see u said that in your question already... my bad

Comment: ok, I've updated my question to what I think the sollution would be. I've also deleted my comments here, to clear things up a bit. Please do the same.

Comment: I use Debian, so I thought the Ubuntu Forum link could help me - but it seems it gets me to a login page?